# OS X El Capitan – File Sharing Restrictions

Tags: macos, permissions, osx-elcapitan, file-sharing

I've got two iMacs running OS X El Capitan. I have setup iMac #1 to share a folder named "Jobs". iMac #1 has a group I created in Users & Groups and myself and my employee are added to that group. I used Get Info on the Jobs folder to set permissions so the group has Read & Write privileges and had it set the same to all enclosed items. From iMac #2 my employee can mount the shared folder and open files and write files, but if he creates a new document or creates a new folder it does not have group permissions. Likewise if I create a new file or folder in Jobs he only has read privileges. I have to keep changing permissions through Get Info. How can I set the shared folder so files we both create can be read and written by either one of us?

Comment: See [this question on apple.se](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31438/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-a-mac-to-make-new-files-inherit-parent-directory-permissio).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a restriction on OS X. I went ahead and bought OS X Server and setup a mac mini as a file server and all is well.