# OSX Write permissions for files on external usb drive always change to read only, when another user changes the file

Tags: macos, networking, operating-system

maybe this is not a real programming question, but I hope you can help.

I really got an annoying behaviour here.
I already read [OS X El Capitan – File Sharing Restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34099647/os-x-el-capitan-file-sharing-restrictions)
But the answer is not making me happy XD

We got the following setup:
- iMac A (El Captain) with an external HDD (TimeMachine saved backup here, plus there are files, which iMac A, iMac B and iMac C are using) User: md, gm
- iMac B (High Sierra) Users: gm
- iMac C (High Sierra) Users: gm

So, in the beginning I set up write permissions for the shared folder in the hdd for actually gm, md.

But:
When User gm changes a file in the HDD using iMac B, the write permission for md is gone and vice versa....

How can I set gm and md to ALWAYS have write permission to a specific folder on the HDD?